# Can't connect my Nest.JS project to dockerized mongodb database

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs, jsx, nestjs-mongodb

I have a dockerized database :

```
 mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongoose-db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
```

I have a Nest.JS project running on http://localhost:3000/ and not inside a dockerized stack.

I want to correctly connect my Nest.JS project to the database :

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://root:1234@localhost:27017', {
      dbName: 'myappdb',
      auth: {
        username: 'root',
        password: '1234',
      },
    }),
    UsersModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
```

}

I tried this confi :

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://root:1234@127.0.0.1:27017/myappdb'),
    UsersModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I'm getting this error :

> [Nest] 16036  - 20/08/2023 14:40:34   ERROR [ExceptionHandler]
> Authentication failed. MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
> at Connection.onMessage (D:\Mes_POCS\token-auth-app\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\connection.ts:450:20)
> at MessageStream. (D:\Mes_POCS\token-auth-app\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\connection.ts:268:56)
> at MessageStream.emit (node:events:514:28)
> at processIncomingData (D:\Mes_POCS\token-auth-app\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\message_stream.ts:194:14)
> at MessageStream._write (D:\Mes_POCS\token-auth-app\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\message_stream.ts:71:5)
> at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
> at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
> at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
> at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)

What is the correct database url ?

Comment: You're duplicating the connection string into a config object. Also please include the error, "can't connect" is not enough detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem in docker compose conf file :

```
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongoose-db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      # MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      # MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MONGODB_USER: root
      MONGODB_DATABASE: db
      MONGODB_PASS: 1234
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
```

And the good root is :

```
MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost:27017/db'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in your mongoose connection.

> For local MongoDB databases, we recommend using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. That is because Node.js 18 and up prefer IPv6 addresses, which means, on many machines, Node.js will resolve localhost to the IPv6 address ::1 and Mongoose will be unable to connect, unless the mongodb instance is running with ipv6 enabled.
>
> https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

That means, you need to use:

```
MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myappdb', {
  authSource: 'admin',
  user: 'root',
  pass: '1234',
})
```

Comment: I' tried this url but still get the same error, i updated my question for more details

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara Have updated my answer. Can you try this?

Comment: i'm still getting  Unable to connect to the database

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara Updated again. Can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use mongodb (the same as the service name in docker-compose)
the connection will be:

```
MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://mongodb:27017/myappdb'),
```

Answer (score -2):

According to the error that has been displayed the Credentials for mongo dB aren't corrects do double check please.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).